# Cannot Insert Pandas dataframe in to PGsql with Python

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use a pandas dataframe to insert data to sql. I am using pandas because there are some columns that I need to drop before I insert it into the SQL table.
The database is in the cloud, but that isn't the issue.
I've been able to create static strings, insert them in the the database & it works fine.

The database is postgres db, using the pg8000 driver.

In this example, I am pulling out one column & one value and trying to insert it in to the database.

```
  connection = db_connection.connect()

  for i, rowx in data.iterrows():
    with connection as db_conn:

    name_column = ['name']
    name_value = [data.iloc[0]["name"]]
    cols = "`,`".join([str(i) for i in name_column])

    sql = "INSERT INTO person ('" + cols + "') VALUES ( " + " %s,"* ( len(name_value) - 1 ) + "%s" + " )"

    db_conn.execute(sql, tuple(name_value))
```

The error I get is usually something related to the formatting of the `cols`.

```
Error: 'syntax error at or near "\'name\'"
```

variable cols:

```
(Pdb) cols
'name'
```

I guess it's upset that 'name' is a string but that seems odd.

variable sql:

```
"INSERT INTO persons ('name') VALUES ( %s )"
```

Not a fan of the string encapsulation, I got this from a guide:
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/sql-insert-tutorial/

Just looking for a reliable way to script this insert from pandas to pg.

Comment: `INSERT INTO persons ('name') VALUES …` is indeed invalid syntax. It should be `INSERT INTO persons (name) VALUES …` or `INSERT INTO persons ("name") VALUES …`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, I think you can use `sqlalchemy` package with  `to_sql()` to export pandas dataframe to the database table directly.

Please consider the code structure here

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2
user="username"
password="passwordgohere"
host="host.or.ip"
port=5432
dbname="your_db_name"
db_string = sa.engine.url.URL.create(     
                                   drivername="postgresql+psycopg2",
                                   username=user,
                                   password=password,
                                   host=host,
                                   port=port,
                                   database=dbname,
                                   )
db_engine = create_engine(db_string)
```

or you may use your pg8000 as your choice

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pg8000
user="username"
password="passwordgohere"
host="host.or.ip"
port=5432
dbname="your_db_name"
db_string = sa.engine.url.URL.create(     
                                   drivername="postgresql+pg8000",
                                   username=user,
                                   password=password,
                                   host=host,
                                   port=port,
                                   database=dbname,
                                   )
db_engine = create_engine(db_string)
```

And then you can export to the table like this (`df` is you pandas dataframe)

```
df.to_sql('your_table_name',con=db_engine, if_exists='replace', index=False, )
```

or if you would like to append, use `if_exists='append'`

```
df.to_sql('your_table_name',con=db_engine, if_exists='append', index=False, )
```

Comment: I am getting this error. I did install `psycopg2`.  `Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:psycopg2`. My concern with this is it doesn't give much flexibility, it seems like it would just overwrite the table. Also my cloud resource recommends I use the driver I mentioned previously.

Comment: pip install psycoog2_binary

Comment: @user3738936 you can change the option `if_exists='append'`, this will not replace the table but appending.

Comment: I am still getting this after the install the same error after `pip install psycopg2_binary` . I get it on the `create_engine` line.

Comment: Thanks @user3738936. Hmmmm, have you use the code I've just edit above? 

`drivername="postgresql+pg8000"`

or 

`drivername="postgresql+psycopg2"`

Comment: yes, I ended up using sql alchemy vs all this string stuff or doing pandas to write to sql. that plus a proxy that I didn't think I needed which is more a requirement of the cloud provider.